# How to SELECT Parent and Child Categories with One Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables First table holds departments of a school and branches. If `Dept` and `ChildDept` values are `0` then it is a department. If `Dept` is different from `0`, then it is a branch of a department. `ParentDept`, `Dept` and `ChildDept` values are not related to `deptID`. They are just for leveling as much as I understand.

**Table: Departments**

```
    deptID     ParentDept     Dept     ChildDept Active Department
----------+--------------+--------+-------------+------+--------
       100|             1|       0|            0|     1|Education
       200|             1|       1|            0|     1|Primary School
       300|             1|       2|            0|     1|Primary Science
       315|             2|       0|            0|     1|Arts
       517|             2|       1|            0|     1|Painting
       518|             2|       2|            0|     1|Music
       555|             2|       3|            0|     0|Dance
```

Second table holds the student information

**Table: Students**

```
    studID         deptID  
----------+--------------- 
         1|            300
         2|            200
         3|            517
         4|            200
         5|            300
         6|            517
         7|            518
```

I have written an SQL query which gets student counts for each department:

```
SELECT d.Department,
       (SELECT COUNT(s.studID) 
        FROM Students AS s 
        WHERE d.deptID = s.deptID) AS studentCount,

       (SELECT Department 
        FROM Departments 
        WHERE deptID = ParentDept) AS ParentDeptName
FROM Departments AS d 
WHERE d.Active = 1
```

The resulting table is as the following:

```
Department      studentCount ParentDeptName
---------------+------------+--------------
Primary Science|           2|Education
Primary School |           2|Education
Painting       |           2|Education
Music          |           1|Education
```

As you see 'Painting' and 'Music' branches belong to 'Arts' department but query result shows 'Education' for every row's parent  department which is wrong. It should be like

```
Department      studentCount ParentDeptName
---------------+------------+--------------
Primary Science|           2|Education
Primary School |           2|Education
Painting       |           2|Arts
Music          |           1|Arts
```

What is wrong with this query or me?

Comment: so you have no relations and looking in one row like 'Painting' you can't tell what parent departament is?

Comment: how u know painting and music is belong to Arts??

Comment: ParentDept, Dept and ChildDept values are for understanding music belongs to arts @ah_hau

Comment: is that mean that if ParentDept is X, the record's parent row ==> the row with ParentDept X and dept 0? Cause your deptid is 3 digit while parent dept = 1 digit only

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT d.Department,
   (SELECT COUNT(s.studID) 
    FROM Students AS s 
    WHERE d.deptID = s.deptID) AS studentCount,
   de.Departments AS ParentDeptName
FROM Departments AS d left join Departments AS de on d.ParentDept = de.deptID 
WHERE d.Active = 1
```

Comment: All the rows of ParentDeptName column returns `null`

Comment: ParentDept and deptID are not related. `d.ParentDept = de.deptID` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

[Check Out My Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4faa8/93) I dont know know how I am going to count :(

```
SELECT (Select Department from Departments a where a.deptID = Departments.ParentDept) As ParentDEPTS,
(Select Department from Departments b where b.deptID = Students.deptID) As StudentDEPTS,  Students.studID AS STUIDS
 FROM Departments
 LEFT JOIN Students
ON Departments.deptID=Students.deptID 
Where 
    Departments.ParentDept is not null 
    AND 
    Students.deptID is not null
    AND 
    Departments.Active =1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @Dept TABLE
(
    deptID INT,
    ParentDept INT,
    Dept INT,     
    ChildDept INT,
    Active INT, 
    Department VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Dept
VALUES
(100, 1, 0, 0, 1, 'Education'),
(200, 1, 1, 0, 1, 'Primary School'),
(300, 1, 2, 0, 1, 'Primary Science'),
(315, 2, 0, 0, 1, 'Arts'),
(517, 2, 1, 0, 1, 'Painting'),
(518, 2, 2, 0, 1, 'Music'),
(555, 2, 3, 0, 0, 'Dance');

DECLARE @Student TABLE
(
    studID INT,
    deptID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Student
VALUES
(1, 300),
(2, 200),
(3, 517),
(4, 200),
(5, 300),
(6, 517),
(7, 518);
```

Now we are going to join student to dept, and then the dept to the parent dept and group them to get our results:

```
SELECT 
    d.Department, 
    COUNT(*) RecCnt, 
    p.Department ParentDept 
FROM @Student s
INNER JOIN @Dept d
    ON s.deptID = d.deptID
INNER JOIN @Dept p
    ON p.ParentDept = d.ParentDept
    AND p.Dept = 0
GROUP BY d.Department, p.Department
```

Here is the output:

```
Department  RecCnt  ParentDept
Music           1   Arts
Painting        2   Arts
Primary School  2   Education
Primary Science 2   Education
```